# Can css affect elements added by document.write?

Tags: javascript, css

If I have this css

```
div.myContainer img.noCampaign { display:none; }
```

and this html/javascript

```
<div class="myContainer">
  <script>document.write('<img class="noCampaign" src="whatever.jpg" />');</script>
</div>
```

I can't seem to get the img element to disappear?

Is there no access to the img element through css when dynamically adding elements with javascript document.write?

/T

Comment: In future, there's no need to sign your name since you already have that big box with your name on it.

Comment: so you want to hide banners... at least paste the full code to see what the advertiser's script does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS styles effect js-generated HTML elements -- in fact, your example code works exactly as expected in my tests. (After adding in the `<script>` element, anyway)

I suspect there's some other problem with your code that's preventing it from behaving how you like -- If you edit the question with the code you actually used we might be able to help you find the problem. There's probably just a simple syntax or precedence error in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can append child elements to the document without using document.write. Add an image element as child to the div.

Use

[document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.createElement)

Answer (score 0):

yes anything that are generated (static or dynamic) is affected by any css (external, embedded or inline)

Answer (score -1):

Would a URL embedded help you ?

```
document.write('<span style="color:#FFFFFF;"> <img src="www.example.com/img.jpg" /> some text and a <a href="http://example.com/" title="example">link</a>');
```